# 0Auth2: when do you use the refresh token to get a new access token? Before or after it expires?

Tags: ios, oauth, oauth-2.0

I'm developing a API to be used with my IOS App and I am curious on the best practice for using the refresh token in oAuth2. I am using the user password grant to generate a access token and refresh token.

If the token expires every 60 minutes then that means every 60 minutes the client will have to make 3 consecutive API calls: 1. use the access token to get the resource from the API, 2. api responds with a invalid token so we need to use the refresh token, 3. now that the token is refreshed we need to try the initial call again.

So, what I am wanting to know is if it's best to refresh the token just before it expires? Or is it better to generate a new access token once the API has responded with a expired token error?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure there's a best practice as such, but it's certainly more efficient to refresh in advance as you then won't make requests that you can know will fail. The cost of the timer to refresh is much less than the cost of the network communication.

You still need handling for the token being invalid on any request as the server could invalidate the token for any number of other reasons, so this is really a 'how can I make this efficient and user friendly' than a 'can I remove some of my code' kind of thing. Handling the error response is the standard, refreshing in advance is the user friendly.

Be cautious about refreshing while you have in-flight requests and you could inadvertently cause a request to fail by invalidating its token...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yea that was another question I had. I wasn't sure how to handle the automatic refresh in regards to it possibly triggering at the same time a user has requested a resource.

Comment: You would need to manage that yourself, perhaps with a queue of in-flight / pending activities so you can see what's happening and schedule a refresh after them. Or you could just assume the chance of a clash is low and refresh anyway depending on what the system is an how much comms it has

Comment: I'm new to iOS programming so is there any articles where I can read up about this? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Not specifically for this that I'm aware of, worth a quick google search though. `NSOperationQueue` would be the route if you did want to manage your network comms for this